# Query for transit Visa in London

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am an Indian holding valid Canadian student visa, I am travelling from Toronto to Chennai via London on same ticket but different PNR with Air Canada and British airways..My luggage goes to Chennai directly but I need change flights in terminals 3 and 5 in Heathrow in 2hr 25min layover, Do I need transit visa in London?!

I don't need to recheck the luggage, my airlines sends it last destination and my airlines said I will be given both boarding passes at Toronto itself...

Comment: Be absolutely sure that AC can check your bags through. If you are sure you purchased a single booking and both PNRs are on the same booking, then you should be OK. But some travel agencies occasionally book flights as separate tickets when the passenger thought they were going to get a single booking. If you have different PNRs you might be in either circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a visa since you already have a Canadian visa. With it, you can enter the UK by presenting your passport (open at the visa page), filled-out landing card and connecting boarding pass, and stay until 23:59 the next day.

Since you have separate tickets, don't follow the international connection signs, but clear immigration, as you'll need to collect and re-check your luggage.